# Sum of terms $1^2-2^2+3^2-...$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Prove that: $$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+...+(-1)^{n-1}n^2=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n(n+1)}{2}$$

I proved it by induction but is there any other way to solve it?
If it was not a proof but rather a question like find the term,how to solve it?

I realized that alternate terms were under same sign but can't understand whether to take $\frac{n}{2}$ odd and even terms[if n is even] or $\frac{n+1}{2}$ odd terms and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ even terms[if n is odd].

I thought of this $$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+5^2=1^2+{(1+2)}^2+{(1+4)}^2-2^2-4^2$$
$$=1^2+1^2+1^2+2(0+2+4)+2^2+4^2-2^2-4^2$$

But then how to generalize??

Comment: $7^2 - 8^2 = (7-8)(7+8) = -7-8$

Comment: @KennyLau This cannot continue by this method.I need to make a generalization in terms of n

Comment: ?? But @KennyLau's remark is very easy to generalize, no?

Answer (score 6):

Notice $$n^2 = \frac{(n-1)n + n(n+1)}{2}
\quad\implies\quad (-1)^{n-1} n^2 = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)n}{2} - (-1)^{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
The sum is a telescoping sum and

$$\require{cancel}\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} k^2 = \color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{grey}{(-1)^{1-1}\frac{(1-1)1}{2}}}}- (-1)^n \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
= (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

Comment: (+1)  How did this answer not receive more up votes??

Answer (score 4):

**Finite differences to get the correct answer**

Apply finite differences to:
 $$a_n=n^2-(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2-\cdots +(-1)^{n-1}1^2$$ using the fact that:

$$a_0=0, a_{n+1}=(n+1)^2-a_n.$$

Then letting $b_{n}=a_{n+1}-a_n$ we get $b_0=1, b_{n+1}=2n+3-b_{n}$. You can argue that $b_n=n+1$ from here, or you can go one step further in the finite differences, setting $c_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$ then you get $c_0=1,$ and $c_{n+1}=2-c_{n}$, so $c_n=1$ and $b_n=n+1$ and $a_n=b_0+b_1+\cdots+b_{n-1}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Now, the value you want is $$(-1)^{n-1}a_n=1-2^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n^2=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

---

**Generating function approach**

Here's an advanced technique called "generating functions," which lets us derive the result and find some general results.

The heart of the technique amounts to writing $n^2$ as a linear combination of polynomials $\binom{n+k}{k}$. Here, you get:

$$n^2=2\binom{n+2}{2}-3\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+0}{0}$$

Then we get:

$$\begin{align}g(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2x^{k}\\
&=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{3}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{2-3(1-x)+(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}
\end{align}$$

We also have:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}x^k=\frac{1}{1+x}$$

This means $$f(x)g(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{n+1}{2}x^{n}$$

This means that $\binom{n+1}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}k^2$, which means that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}k^2=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{2}$$

---

More generally, if $p$ is a polynomial then there is a polynomial $q$ of the same degree and some constant $c$ such that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}p(k)=c+(-1)^{n}q(n)$$

If $p(n)=\binom{n+k}{k}$, then $c=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ and $q(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{k+1-i}}\binom{n+i}{i}$.

For example, $p(n)=n+1$ gives $c=\frac{1}{4}$ and $q(n)=\frac{1}{2}\binom{n+1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}\binom{n}{0}=\frac{2n+3}{4}$ and you get the result:

$$1-2+3-\cdots+(-1)^{n}(n+1)=\frac{1}{4}+(-1)^n\frac{2n+3}{4}$$

---

The case $n^2=2\binom{n+2}{2}-3\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+0}{0}$ giving constant $c=2\frac{1}{8}-3\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=0$, and:

$$\begin{align}
q(n)=&2\left(\frac{1}{2}\binom{n+2}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\binom{n+1}{1}+\frac{1}{8}\right)\\
&-3\left(\frac{1}{2}\binom{n+1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
&+\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Which simplifies to:

$$q(n)=\binom{n+2}{2}-\binom{n+1}{1}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)-2(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

---

Even more general, if we have $p_k(n)=\binom{n+k}{k}$, then we can compute for any $a\neq 0,1$ the formula for $\sum_{i=0}^{n} p_k(i)a^i$. To do so, we set $b=a^{-1}$, and use partial fractions to get:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}(1-bx)}=\frac{1}{1-b}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\dfrac{\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{i+1}}+\dfrac{\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)^{k+1}}{1-bx}$$

The coefficient of $x^n$ on the left side is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{i+k}{i}b^{n-i}$$ which is $b^n$ times the quantity we wanted, since $b=a^{-1}$.

The coefficient of $x^n$ on the right side is:

$$\frac{1}{1-b}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)^{k-i}\binom{n+i}{i} + b^n\left(\frac{b}{b-1}\right)^{k+1}$$

Replacing $a=b^{-1}$ and multiplying by $b^{-n}=a^{n}$ we get:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{i+k}{k}a^i = \frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\dfrac{\binom{n+i}{i}}{(1-a)^{k-i}} + \frac{1}{(1-a)^{k+1}}$$

Since we know that the $p_k$ form a basis for the polynomials, we get that for any polynomial $p$ and any fixed $a\neq 0,1$ there is a polynomial $q(x)$ of the same degree and constant $c$ such that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^ip(i) = c + a^{n+1}q(n)$$

More generally, if $p(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}d_i\binom{n+i}{i}$, then we can define $D_i(x)=d_ix+d_{i+1}x^2+\cdots+d_kx^{k+1-i}$ and get:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} p(i)a^i = D_0\left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)-a^{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}D_{j}\left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)\binom{n+j}{j}$$

Answer (score 2):

You could use formal manipulations with a truncated power series:
$$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \right) = 1 + 2x + \cdots + n x^{n-1} \\
x \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \right) = x + 2x^2 + \cdots + n x^n \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \right) \right) = 1 + 4x + \cdots + n^2 x^{n-1}
$$

Now evaluate the derivatives on the left hand side, and then substitute $x := -1$.

Comment: Some simpler solution please

Comment: @sayan Generalizations lead to more complex solutions, and what's wrong with something being complex? I do not think this one is over the top.

Comment: Actually I haven't yet learnt calculus!!

Comment: @sayan And so, because you haven't learned calculus yet, you wish to bar viewers from content they may find useful when visiting your question?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I never wanted that!!

Comment: @sayan We're obviously not mind readers, and its not always about what *you* want. You're not the only one coming to this to find answers, other users have that right too you know.

Comment: Besides, getting more than what you asked for is a good thing. Perhaps in a few years you can come back and understand this answer. I still go over old answers to my questions that I haven't fully understood yet @sayan

Comment: My apologies to all!Sorry

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: A classic trick is for example $1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 = (1^2 +2^2+3^2+4^2) - 2(2^2+4^2)= S_4 - 2^3(1^2+2^2)= S_4 - 8S_2$. Now you can generalize this with $4,2$ are replaced by $2n, n$. Can you finish it? If the last term is *odd*, then isolate it and use up to the preceeding term which is *even*. So it can always be done this way...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{r=1}^{2n}(-1)^{r-1}r^2=\sum_{r=1}^n\{(2r-1)^2-(2r)^2\}=\sum_{r=1}^n(1-4r)$$

$$=\dfrac n2(1-4+1-4n)=\cdots=(-1)^{2n-1}\dfrac{2n(2n+1)}2$$

Now $$\sum_{r=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{r-1}r^2=(2n+1)^2+\sum_{r=1}^{2n}(-1)^{r-1}r^2=?$$

Answer (score 1):

For odd $n$, $(-1)^{n-1}=1$, so
$$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots+n^2\\
=1^2+(-2^2+3^2)+(-4^2+5^2)+\cdots+(-(n-1)^2+n^2)\\
=1+\color{blue}{(-2+3)}(2+3)+\color{blue}{(-4+5)}(4+5)+\cdots+\color{blue}{(-(n-1)+n)}((n-1)+n)\\
=\color{blue}{1\cdot}\left(1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+(n-1)+n\right)\\
=\frac {n(n+1)}2\\
=(-1)^{n-1}\frac {n(n+1)}2$$
For even $n$, $(-1)^{n-1}=-1$, so
$$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots+n^2\\
=(1^2-2^2)+(3^2-4^2)+(5^2-6^2)+\cdots+((n-1)^2-n^2)\\
=\color{orange}{(1-2)}(1+2)+\color{orange}{(3-4)}(3+4)+\color{orange}{(5-6)}(5+6)+\cdots+\color{orange}{((n-1)-n)}((n-1)+n)\\
=\color{orange}-(1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+(n-1)+n)\\
=-\frac {n(n+1)}2\\
=(-1)^{n-1}\frac {n(n+1)}2$$
Hence, for both odd and even $n$, 
$$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots+n^2=(-1)^{n-1}\frac {n(n+1)}2$$

Answer (score 0):

For example, if $n$ is odd, $n=2k-1$ then we obtain:
$$LS=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-8\cdot\frac{k(k-1)(2k-1)}{6}=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-8\cdot\frac{\frac{n+1}{2}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot n}{6}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: I know that but can I make such an assumption?

Comment: @sayan If $n$ is odd then there is an integer $k$ for which $n=2k-1$. If $n$ is even then there is an integer $k$ for which $n=2k$, Thus, you Indeed can make this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n +1$.

So $(2n-1)^2 - (2n)^2 = 4n^2 -4n +1 - 4n^2 = -4n+1$.

So $\sum_{k=1}^{n=2m} (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = \sum_{j=1}^m [(2j-1)^2 - (2j)^2]=\sum_{j=1}^m [-4j +1]= -4(\sum j) + m = -4*\frac {m(m+1)}2 + m = -2m(m+1) +m=m(-2(m+1) + 1)=m(-2m-1)=-m(2m+1)= -\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

..... if $n$ is even.

If $n=2m+1$ is odd then $\sum_{k=1}^{n=2m+1}(-1)^{k-1}k^2 = [\sum_{k=1}^{2m=2n-1}(-1)^{k-1}k^2] + n^2$

$= -\frac {(n-1)((n-1) + 1)}2 + n^2= n^2 - \frac {n(n-1)}2 = \frac {2n^2 -n(n-1)}2 = \frac {n(2n - (n-1)}2 = \frac {n(n+1)}2$

So either way ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice trick. For each $k$,
$$k^2=\frac{(k-1)k}2+\frac{k(k+1)}2=a_{k-1}+a_k$$
say.
Then
$$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots\pm n^2
=a_0+a_1-a_1-a_2+a_2+a_3-\cdots\pm a_{n-1}\mp a_n$$
and almost all of these terms cancel.